# Cloud Run, TSL connection

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I need a connection from cloud run to the database server. In that case, ssl/tls authentication is required.

I posted a question yesterday, but the answer keeps saying that TLS/SSL is not created separately in cloud run. But then, what does the URL below describe?

https://cloud.google.com/anthos/run/docs/managed-tls

I need to put the cert file in etc/ssl/certs/ Which method is the easiest? I really need help thank you!

Comment: What error are you seeing now? What happened after following the steps our community members provided?

Comment: @RobertG Hi I figured out now but still wonder about https://cloud.google.com/anthos/run/docs/managed-tls, Google can give me the certificate-ca.crt or not?? can I download it or do I have to buy somewhere else?

Comment: Have a break and ask yourselves: between what and what do you need a TSL authentication? It's not in ingress of Cloud Run, but in egress. That being said, you don't care of Cloud Run TLS feature (which is for ingress only) the Cloud Run egress SSL config is to manage in your code. And on your database instance!

Comment: @hoapol, please post your answer on how you resolved this question so that other community members will find this helpful.